# Wrong audit question

Tags: support, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I've just failed audit on [Lite (ansi c 89) os for custom cpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930526/lite-ansi-c-89-os-for-custom-cpu), voting that it should be closed. In my opinion it is either recommendation ("if there are any alternative open source os") or too broad question ("anyone has had any success porting <...> what we should look out for").

I looked around meta and understand how it was selected for audit and that I, personally, should just ignore this result, but I want to draw attention to question itself so it can be actioned upon and, hopefully, disappear from "candidates to audit" list.

Comment: While an interesting project, I agree that this question should be closed.

Comment: closed now, thanks to the meta effect

Comment: There was also a [Close review audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2669014) connected to this same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The criteria for audits are such that any opposite action will make the post ineligible. In the case of close vote audits where you shouldn't close, simply downvoting or casting a close vote makes it ineligible to be an audit.